# How to create an HttpResponse object with dummy values in ktor Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, httpresponse, ktor

I am using ktor for developing a microservice in Kotlin. For testing a method, I need to create a dummy HttpResponse (`io.ktor.client.statement.HttpResponse` to be specific) object with status = 200 and body = some json data.
Any idea how I can create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mockk](https://mockk.io/) or a similar kind of library to mock an `HttpResponse`. Unfortunately, this is complicated because `HttpRequest`, `HttpResponse`, and `HttpClient` objects are tightly coupled with the `HttpClientCall`. Here is an example of how you can do that:

```
val call = mockk<HttpClientCall> {
    every { client } returns mockk {}
    coEvery { receive(io.ktor.util.reflect.typeInfo<String>()) } returns "body"
    every { coroutineContext } returns EmptyCoroutineContext
    every { attributes } returns Attributes()
    every { request } returns object : HttpRequest {
        override val call: HttpClientCall = this@mockk
        override val attributes: Attributes = Attributes()
        override val content: OutgoingContent = object : OutgoingContent.NoContent() {}
        override val headers: Headers = Headers.Empty
        override val method: HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Get
        override val url: Url = Url("/")
    }

    every { response } returns object : HttpResponse() {
        override val call: HttpClientCall = this@mockk
        override val content: ByteReadChannel = ByteReadChannel("body")
        override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
        override val headers: Headers = Headers.Empty
        override val requestTime: GMTDate = GMTDate.START
        override val responseTime: GMTDate = GMTDate.START
        override val status: HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        override val version: HttpProtocolVersion = HttpProtocolVersion.HTTP_1_1
    }
}

val response = call.response
```

Comment: I am getting an error :- `no answer found for: HttpClientCall(#1).receive(TypeInfoImpl(type=class kotlin.String, reifiedType=class java.lang.String, kotlinType=kotlin.String), continuation {})`. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I've added a stub for `HttpClientCall.receive` method to the code in my answer. If you get that kind of error you need to provide stubs for non-implemented methods or properties.

Comment: I had to replace 'receive' to 'bodyNullable' in coEvery, otherwise working fine

Answer (score 2):

With Ktor 2, it's best to use `externalServices` block instead of attempting to mock `HttpResponse`. That way you don't need to attempt and mock the internals of Ktor, and it's not complicated at all.

```kotlin
externalServices {
    hosts("https://your-fake-host") {
        routing {
            get("/api/v1/something/{id}/") {
                call.respondText(
                    "{}",
                    contentType = ContentType.Application.Json,
                    status = HttpStatusCode.OK
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This need to be wrapped with `testApplication`

Comment: Great, thanks for the pointer! I ended up using a MockEngine (https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-testing.html#test-client) that creates me a properly populated response object.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with following. I only needed to pass a status code and description, so I didn't bother about other fields.

```kotlin
class CustomHttpResponse(
    private val statusCode: Int,
    private val description: String
) :
    HttpResponse() {
    @InternalAPI
    override val content: ByteReadChannel
        get() = ByteReadChannel("")

    override val call: HttpClientCall
        get() = HttpClientCall(HttpClient())

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = EmptyCoroutineContext

    override val headers: Headers
        get() = Headers.Empty

    override val requestTime: GMTDate
        get() = GMTDate()

    override val responseTime: GMTDate
        get() = GMTDate()

    override val status: HttpStatusCode
        get() = HttpStatusCode(statusCode, description)

    override val version: HttpProtocolVersion
        get() = HttpProtocolVersion(name = "HTTP", major = 1, minor = 1)}
```